# Why is Matlab is not reading an empty cell while running an if statement?

Tags: string, matlab, is-empty, equivalence

I am using the loop below to isolate instances where data was recorded versus those with no data. The data set is very large (varying from 1000-6000 depending on the column) and of mixed data types, so the only practical solution I can think of is using loops.

I can't get the if or while statement to accurately read a blank space. It runs without any errors if I use a for loop, but it never enters the first half of the if-meaning I end up copying, not separating my data. The varying sizes of data make a for loop undesirable.

```
while (isempty(andover_all{j,1})==1) 
  if andover_all{h,33}==''; 
      current_data{k,4}= formated_date{j};  
      k=k+1;
  else
    current_data{i,1}=formated_date{j};
    current_data{i,2}=andover_data{33}(j);
    i=i+1;
 end
 h=h+1;
end
```

Andover_all is an array of strings, current_data and andover_data are cell arrays with mixed data types. I have tried using isempty, [], cellfun(@isempty,andover_data), and a function eq.m that allows me to compare cell elements-none of them work. I also don't want to remove empty cells from the data, just skip over them.

Please let me know if you have any ideas

Answer (score 2):

The empties are indeed something to get used to. It's like working with `inf` or `NaN`; what should things like `NaN==NaN` or `1/0==inf` return? There's special rules for these guys. Simple ones, but you have to get to know them. To make all the special rules for these guys less of a burden, more intuitive and more readable, MATLAB has special functions for them: `isinf` (to detect `inf`), `isnan` (to detect NaN) and `isfinite` (to detect *either* `inf` or `NaN`).

The empties also have special behavior and special rules that require some getting used to. If you think about it, it all makes sense in the end: What should `[]==[]` return? or `1==''`?

Empty, of course. And even if `[]==false` is empty, `[]` is `false` when evaluated by an `if`. Easy right? :)

Unfortunately, there is no equivalent of `isinf` or `isnan` to detect empties of a specific type (there is **no** `isemptycell` or `isemptychar` etc.) There *is* an equivalent of `isfinite` for empties (which is `isempty`), which catches *either* `''`, `{}`, or `[]`.

But sometimes it is desirable to have checks for *specific* empties, as in your case. The empties preserve their *class*. This means, `{}` is really a cell, and `[]` really an array of `double`s.

Therefore, to detect empty cells:

```
>> a = {};
>> iscell(a) && isempty(a)
ans = 
    1
```

to detect empty strings:

```
>> a = '';
>> ischar(a) && isempty(a)
ans = 
    1
```

and to detect empty arrays:

```
>> a = [];
>> isnumeric(a) && isempty(a)
ans = 
    1
```